# Using Regex to find entities (starting with a capital or digit)

Tags: python, regex

I have text as given below, I am trying to extract meaningful information from the text (The Terms starting with capital letters or digit)

```
The text is : "My name is Sam Helsen or Sam H Helsen son of M Helsen working at 3M technologies as the President of Sales"
```

The information I am trying to extract is given in the mentioned list:

```
info = ["My",'Sam Helsen', 'Sam H Helsen', 'M Helsen', '3M', 'President of Sales'
```

I have used the below regex, which extract some of the information from the above list, but not all.

```
Regex : re.findall(r'\b[A-Z1-9][\d\w]+(?:[\'\s-]\b[A-Z]\w+)*', sent, re.DOTALL)
Output: ['Sam Helsen', 'Sam', 'Helsen', 'Helsen', '3M', 'President', 'Sale']
```

By looking at the regex, I get it why I am unable to fetch all the information, but when I modify the regex it changes other outputs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the logic behind this since I don't see `My` in the list? Or, in `President of Sales` the word `of` starts with lower case?

Comment: how are you determining to select number of words..e.g. why `3M` and why not `3M technologies`?

Comment: You will never get a regex that realises that "President of Sales" should be together but "Helsen or Sam" should not.

Comment: i think the term you should be looking for is _artificial intelligence_

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, Actually I filtered Stop words thats the reason 'My' is not mentioned in the output. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Hi  Mark, I am not asking for the regex to determine whether "of" or "or" should be taken into account. I am just asking for a regex that could capture a whole entity with a of in middle such as "President of Sales".  I tried placing the of in my regex, but somehow I wasnt able to get the output that i desire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?<!^|\n|[.!?] )[A-Z\d][A-Za-z\d]*(?: (?:of )?[A-Z\d][A-Za-z\d]*)*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE9qO1/2).

---

Breakdown:

```
(?<!                     make sure this isn't the first word. Should not be preceded by...
   ^                     ...nothing
   |\n                   ...or a newline
   |[.!?] )              ...or another sentence
[A-Z\d][A-Za-z\d]*       match a word if it starts with a capital or a digit
(?:                      continue matching infinitely as long as...
    (?:of )?             ...the next word is "of" and/or...
   [A-Z\d][A-Za-z\d]*    ...the following word is capitalized
)*
```

Comment: I think that is cleaner than mine :)

Comment: @ Rawing, Thanks, the solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

Don't really get what you are trying to do, but will give a try for my answer:

```
/\s(([0-9]?[A-Z]\w*)+((\sof)?\s?[0-9]?[A-Z]\w*)*)/g
```

`\s` - forces the words to have a space before so it can't be the first one

`([0-9]?[A-Z]\w*)+` - matches the first word with capital or number as first char

`(\sof)?\s?` - matches the connector ' of ' if there is one or space between two capital words

`[0-9]?[A-Z]\w*)*` - Matches any other word that might come after

http://regexr.com/3detv